# Python: Reorder dataframe rows w.r.t. column conditioning

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Have got an input dataframe `df` like below which holds data with multiple `category-main_group-sub_group`. Here as a sample input have provided for single category and single main_group.
So the thing is to reorder rows among sub_group value for each `Category-main_group` combination[For eg., Here we got two subgroups `KIWI FRUIT` and `MANDARIN` for `Fruit-CITRUS` combination]. On considering Type column, each `sub_group and type` combination need to be placed alternatively as shown in expected output.

***Input Dataframe df:***

```
Category    main_group      sub_group       Item            Type        item_order      row
Fruit       CITRUS          KIWI FRUIT      GreenKiwi       Loose           1           row_1
Fruit       CITRUS          KIWI FRUIT      GoldKiwi        Loose           2           row_1
Fruit       CITRUS          KIWI FRUIT      OtherKiwi       Loose           3           row_1
Fruit       CITRUS          KIWI FRUIT      PP GreenKiwi    PP              4           row_1
Fruit       CITRUS          KIWI FRUIT      PP GoldKiwi     PP              5           row_1
Fruit       CITRUS          KIWI FRUIT      PP OtherKiwi    PP              6           row_1
Fruit       CITRUS          MANDARIN        MandarinAfourer Loose           7           row_1
Fruit       CITRUS          MANDARIN        MandarinTangold Loose           8           row_1
Fruit       CITRUS          MANDARIN        PP Mandarin     PP              9           row_1
Fruit       MANGOES         NECTARINES      NectaYellow     Loose           10          row_1
Fruit       MANGOES         NECTARINES      NectaWhite      Loose           11          row_1
Fruit       MANGOES         PEACHES         PeachYellow     Loose           12          row_1
Fruit       MANGOES         PEACHES         PeachWhite      Loose           13          row_1
Vegg        TOM/CAP         TOMATO          Tomato Truss    Loose           14          row_2
Vegg        TOM/CAP         TOMATO          Tomato Roma     Loose           15          row_2
Vegg        TOM/CAP         CUCUMBER        Capsicum Mini   Loose           16          row_2
Vegg        TOM/CAP         CUCUMBER        Capsicum Red    Loose           17          row_2
Vegg        ONION           ONION           Onion Red       Loose           18          row_2
Vegg        ONION           ONION           PP Onion        PP              19          row_2
```

***Expected Output:***

```
Category    main_group      sub_group       Item            Type        item_order      old_item_order      row
Fruit       CITRUS          KIWI FRUIT      GreenKiwi       Loose           1               1               row_1
Fruit       CITRUS          MANDARIN        MandarinAfourer Loose           2               7               row_1
Fruit       CITRUS          KIWI FRUIT      GoldKiwi        Loose           3               2               row_1
Fruit       CITRUS          MANDARIN        MandarinTangold Loose           4               8               row_1
Fruit       CITRUS          KIWI FRUIT      OtherKiwi       Loose           5               3               row_1
Fruit       CITRUS          KIWI FRUIT      PP GreenKiwi    PP              6               4               row_1
Fruit       CITRUS          MANDARIN        PP Mandarin     PP              7               9               row_1
Fruit       CITRUS          KIWI FRUIT      PP GoldKiwi     PP              8               5               row_1
Fruit       CITRUS          KIWI FRUIT      PP OtherKiwi    PP              9               6               row_1
Fruit       MANGOES         NECTARINES      NectaYellow     Loose           10              10              row_1
Fruit       MANGOES         PEACHES         PeachYellow     Loose           11              12              row_1
Fruit       MANGOES         NECTARINES      NectaWhite      Loose           12              11              row_1
Fruit       MANGOES         PEACHES         PeachWhite      Loose           13              13              row_1
Vegg        TOM/CAP         TOMATO          Tomato Truss    Loose           14              14              row_2
Vegg        TOM/CAP         CUCUMBER        Capsicum Mini   Loose           15              16              row_2
Vegg        TOM/CAP         TOMATO          Tomato Roma     Loose           16              15              row_2
Vegg        TOM/CAP         CUCUMBER        Capsicum Red    Loose           17              17              row_2
Vegg        ONION           ONION           Onion Red       Loose           18              18              row_2
Vegg        ONION           ONION           PP Onion        PP              19              19              row_2
```

**Additional Condition added on edit:** this sorting reorder process need to be done only if `df['main_group'] == ['CITRUS','MANGOES','TOM/CAP']`, other groups should not be reordered and keep the order as it is(like here 'ONION' need to be excluded).

Kindly help me through this. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to compute a sub-order of the sub_group. Then sort by type and this order.

Example using the efficient [`np.lexsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html):

```
out = df.iloc[np.lexsort([df.groupby(['Type', 'sub_group']).cumcount(), df['Type']])]
```

With pandas' [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
(df.assign(sub_order=df.groupby(['Type', 'sub_group']).cumcount())
   .sort_values(by=['Type', 'sub_order'])
)
```

Output:

```
  Category main_group   sub_group             Item   Type  item_order    row
0    Fruit     CITRUS  KIWI FRUIT        GreenKiwi  Loose           1  row_1
6    Fruit     CITRUS    MANDARIN  MandarinAfourer  Loose           7  row_1
1    Fruit     CITRUS  KIWI FRUIT         GoldKiwi  Loose           2  row_1
7    Fruit     CITRUS    MANDARIN  MandarinTangold  Loose           8  row_1
2    Fruit     CITRUS  KIWI FRUIT        OtherKiwi  Loose           3  row_1
3    Fruit     CITRUS  KIWI FRUIT     PP GreenKiwi     PP           4  row_1
8    Fruit     CITRUS    MANDARIN      PP Mandarin     PP           9  row_1
4    Fruit     CITRUS  KIWI FRUIT      PP GoldKiwi     PP           5  row_1
5    Fruit     CITRUS  KIWI FRUIT     PP OtherKiwi     PP           6  row_1
```

##### update with more columns:

```
out = df.iloc[np.lexsort([df.groupby(['Type', 'sub_group']).cumcount(),
                          df['Type'], df['main_group'], df['Category']])]
```

Or:

```
(df.assign(sub_order=df.groupby(['Type', 'sub_group']).cumcount())
   .sort_values(by=['Category', 'main_group', 'Type', 'sub_order'])
)
```

Comment: this works partially, as I already mentioned have got multiple Category and main_group in original data. So on applying this method, su_group get sorted irrespective of the category and main_group which should not happen.

Comment: Kindly edit the answer by including Category and main_group as well.

Comment: @user12345 can you update your example with a few extra rows with a different Category and main_group? Otherwise the expected order is ambiguous

Comment: included additional rows and one more condition to be considered

Comment: See update, note that the TOM/CAP and ONION order is swapped (O < T), if this is an issue you can perform sub-sorting within a `groupby`

Comment: works perfect! thanks much. Also, is there any way i can perform this reordering for specific main_group alone as mentioned in question

Comment: What do you mean by "*specific main_group*"? Only a subset of the main_group and leave the others unsorted? In this case a different logic would be needed (maybe this should be a separate question?)

Comment: you are right. leave others unsorted. but how can i put this alone as separate question?

Comment: Open an [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)? ;)

Comment: Kindly can you add solution for this as well here. Means a lot

Comment: I think it would be better for future readers to separate, this one is about custom interleaved order sorting. Subsorting selected groups is quite different. Large very specific questions are less useful for future reader than short focused questions.

Comment: Follow up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75111451/python-reorder-dataframe-rows-for-specific-set-of-group