# Python: Reorder dataframe rows for specific set of group

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Have got an input dataframe `df` like below which holds data with multiple `category-main_group-sub_group`.
So the thing is to reorder rows among sub_group value for each `Category-main_group` combination[For eg., Here we got two subgroups `KIWI FRUIT` and `MANDARIN` for `Fruit-CITRUS` combination and so on]. On considering Type column, each `sub_group and type` combination need to be placed alternatively as shown in expected output.

This sorting reorder process need to be done only if `df['main_group'] == ['CITRUS','TOM/CAP']`, other groups should not be reordered and keep the order as it is(like here 'MANGOES' and 'ONION' need to be excluded for sorting).

***Input Dataframe df:***

```
Category    main_group      sub_group       Item            Type        item_order      row
Fruit       CITRUS          KIWI FRUIT      GreenKiwi       Loose           1           row_1
Fruit       CITRUS          KIWI FRUIT      GoldKiwi        Loose           2           row_1
Fruit       CITRUS          KIWI FRUIT      OtherKiwi       Loose           3           row_1
Fruit       CITRUS          KIWI FRUIT      PP GreenKiwi    PP              4           row_1
Fruit       CITRUS          KIWI FRUIT      PP GoldKiwi     PP              5           row_1
Fruit       CITRUS          KIWI FRUIT      PP OtherKiwi    PP              6           row_1
Fruit       CITRUS          MANDARIN        MandarinAfourer Loose           7           row_1
Fruit       CITRUS          MANDARIN        MandarinTangold Loose           8           row_1
Fruit       CITRUS          MANDARIN        PP Mandarin     PP              9           row_1
Fruit       MANGOES         NECTARINES      NectaYellow     Loose           10          row_1
Fruit       MANGOES         NECTARINES      NectaWhite      Loose           11          row_1
Fruit       MANGOES         PEACHES         PeachYellow     Loose           12          row_1
Fruit       MANGOES         PEACHES         PeachWhite      Loose           13          row_1
Vegg        TOM/CAP         TOMATO          Tomato Truss    Loose           14          row_2
Vegg        TOM/CAP         TOMATO          Tomato Roma     Loose           15          row_2
Vegg        TOM/CAP         CUCUMBER        Capsicum Mini   Loose           16          row_2
Vegg        TOM/CAP         CUCUMBER        Capsicum Red    Loose           17          row_2
Vegg        ONION           ONION           Onion Red       Loose           18          row_2
Vegg        ONION           ONION           PP Onion        PP              19          row_2
```

***Expected Output:***

```
Category    main_group      sub_group       Item            Type        item_order      old_item_order      row
Fruit       CITRUS          KIWI FRUIT      GreenKiwi       Loose           1               1               row_1
Fruit       CITRUS          MANDARIN        MandarinAfourer Loose           2               7               row_1
Fruit       CITRUS          KIWI FRUIT      GoldKiwi        Loose           3               2               row_1
Fruit       CITRUS          MANDARIN        MandarinTangold Loose           4               8               row_1
Fruit       CITRUS          KIWI FRUIT      OtherKiwi       Loose           5               3               row_1
Fruit       CITRUS          KIWI FRUIT      PP GreenKiwi    PP              6               4               row_1
Fruit       CITRUS          MANDARIN        PP Mandarin     PP              7               9               row_1
Fruit       CITRUS          KIWI FRUIT      PP GoldKiwi     PP              8               5               row_1
Fruit       CITRUS          KIWI FRUIT      PP OtherKiwi    PP              9               6               row_1
Fruit       MANGOES         NECTARINES      NectaYellow     Loose           10              10              row_1
Fruit       MANGOES         NECTARINES      NectaWhite      Loose           11              11              row_1
Fruit       MANGOES         PEACHES         PeachYellow     Loose           12              12              row_1
Fruit       MANGOES         PEACHES         PeachWhite      Loose           13              13              row_1
Vegg        TOM/CAP         TOMATO          Tomato Truss    Loose           14              14              row_2
Vegg        TOM/CAP         CUCUMBER        Capsicum Mini   Loose           15              16              row_2
Vegg        TOM/CAP         TOMATO          Tomato Roma     Loose           16              15              row_2
Vegg        TOM/CAP         CUCUMBER        Capsicum Red    Loose           17              17              row_2
Vegg        ONION           ONION           Onion Red       Loose           18              18              row_2
Vegg        ONION           ONION           PP Onion        PP              19              19              row_2
```

Tried Code:

```
to_sort = ['CITRUS', 'TOM/CAP']
out = (df.assign(sub_order=df.groupby(['Type', 'sub_group'], group_keys=False, sort=False).cumcount()).apply(lambda g: g.sort_values(by=['Category', 'main_group', 'Type', 'sub_order']) if g.name[1] in to_sort else g))
```

but getting `NameError: name 'to_sort' is not defined`

Kindly help me through this. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you add the information from the previous question, so this stands alone?

Comment: It's a big explanation, so that have added in the link for that previous one

Comment: @user12345 I suggest your provide a minimal example (see my answer for a suggestion of a small example derived from your other question)

Comment: I'm voting to close. This question does not stand on its own, limiting its utility to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this input:

```
   Category main_group  value
0     Fruit     CITRUS    1.0
1     Fruit     CITRUS    5.0
2     Fruit     CITRUS    0.0
3     Fruit    MANGOES    2.0
4     Fruit    MANGOES    1.0
5     Fruit    MANGOES    4.0
6     Fruit    MANGOES    0.0
7      Vegg    TOM/CAP    9.0
8      Vegg    TOM/CAP    2.0
9      Vegg    TOM/CAP    1.0
10     Vegg      ONION    0.0
11     Vegg      ONION    NaN
```

You can only sort CITRUS and TOM/CAP by using [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
to_sort = ['CITRUS', 'TOM/CAP']

out = (df
   .groupby(['Category', 'main_group'], group_keys=False, sort=False)
   .apply(lambda g: g.sort_values(by='value') if g.name[1] in to_sort else g)
)
```

Output:

```
   Category main_group  value
2     Fruit     CITRUS    0.0  #
0     Fruit     CITRUS    1.0  # this is now sorted
1     Fruit     CITRUS    5.0  #
3     Fruit    MANGOES    2.0     #
4     Fruit    MANGOES    1.0     # this remains
5     Fruit    MANGOES    4.0     #  unchanged
6     Fruit    MANGOES    0.0     #
9      Vegg    TOM/CAP    1.0  #
8      Vegg    TOM/CAP    2.0  # this is now sorted
7      Vegg    TOM/CAP    9.0  #
10     Vegg      ONION    0.0
11     Vegg      ONION    NaN
```

Comment: how can this be applied using lexsort ?

Comment: on trying above logic getting 'NameError: name 'to_sort' is not defined'. but it's defined in code. not sure what's happening

Comment: I just double checked and it's working fine for me, can you provide a fully reproducible example in the question?

Comment: have added details in qus with sample

Comment: what does g.name[1] represents here ?